# Mesh optimization for "fast" simulation

Tags: gazebo, collision, xacro

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
i created a robot model with some links. All links are meshes, like the UR10 from Universal Robotics has its shoulder_link, elbow_link and so on.
For example the simulation for the UR-10 uses the meshes as collision elements. How much would it improve the speed of our simulation to improve the meshes (ex the base from 300 faces to 50 faces). Is there a rule for a good number of faces for collision meshes or is it mostly better to use simple shapes?
What is the most common way for collision objects in Gazebos simulations?
What are "good" meshes?
And how would it improve the simulation to improve all meshes (to let me say 50% of all faces as example)
Is the number of faces of the visual mesh influencing the simulation-performance?
Best regards
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20108/mesh-optimization-for-%22fast%22-simulation/) by [vonunwerth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6075/vonunwerth/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Partial answer here. My impression is that the number of contacts, not mesh geometry, is one of the largest bottlenecks in simulation.

It may be worth your time to experiment with different maxContacts values in your *.urdf/xacro, e.g:

```
<gazebo reference="LINK_NAME" >
  <maxContacts="NUMBER_OF_CONTACTS"/>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I personally noticed a significant improvement by using cylindrical primitives to approximate the robot links. Be careful, in this case you will have to manually place the reference systems and decide the dimensions so that these collision meshes overlap perfectly or with a small margin with the visual meshes of your robot.

Primitives are one way, otherwise if you want to test it faster I would recommend using the convex hull method to approximate your meshes with simpler geometry and fewer faces.

See here:
[link text](https://adamconkey.medium.com/collision-meshes-for-simulating-robots-in-gazebo-ccc647d8b87d)

---

Originally posted by [gsisinna](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/125845/gsisinna/) with karma: 21 on 2023-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1